# fixed number format with different lengths in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with a Oracle Query
I have a query:

scenario 1: select to_char('1737388250',what format???) from dual;

```
expected output: 173,7388250
```

scenario 2: select to_char('173738825034',what format??) from dual;

```
expected output: 173,738825034
```

scenario 3: select to_char('17373882',what format??) from dual;

```
expected output: 173,73882
```

I need a query to satify all above scenarios?
Can some one help please?

Comment: Just to make sure: you want a space after the comma? That doesn't seem like a common "number format" (meaning, a way to format actual ***numbers***).

Comment: @mathguy: There is no space after the comma in the expected output text, you can check it out by copy/past it into your text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ***is*** possible to get the desired result with a customized format model given to `to_char`; I show one example below. However, any solution along these lines is just a hack (a solution that should work correctly in all cases, but using features of the language in ways they weren't intended to be used).

Here is one example - this will work if your "inputs" are positive integers greater than 999 (that is: at least four digits).

```
with
  sample_data (num) as (
    select 1737388250 from dual union all
    select      12338 from dual
  )
select num, to_char(num, rpad('fm999G', length(num) + 3, '9')) as formatted
from   sample_data
;

       NUM  FORMATTED   
----------  ------------
1737388250  173,7388250 
     12338  123,38
```

This assumes comma is the "group separator" in `nls_numeric_characters`; if it isn't, that can be controlled with the third argument to `to_char`. Note that the format modifier `fm` is needed so that no space is prepended to the resulting string; and the +3 in the second argument to `rpad` accounts for the extra characters in the format model (f, m and G).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select TO_CHAR(1737388250, '999,99999999999') from dual;
```

Take a look [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: it is not working. I am expecting comma after the first 3 characters irrespective of the length of the number. your query is not working

Comment: If leading spaces are the problem, you can use select ltrim(TO_CHAR(1737388, '999,999999999999')) from dual;

Comment: I need a comma after first 3 characters. your query simply returns:1737388 without decimail.

Comment: try this, select TO_CHAR(1737388250, '999,999,999,999,999,999') sal from dual;

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is different so you can use substr and concatanation as follows:

```
select substr(your_number,1,3)
|| case when your_number >= 1000 then ',' end
|| substr(1737388250,4)
from dual;
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d04076b87719ecd785fde88f7530a6e3)

Answer (score 0):

Your "number" is enclosed in single-quotes.  This makes it a character string, albeit a string of only numeric characters.  But a character string, nonetheless.  So it makes no sense to pass a character string to TO_CHAR.

Everyone's suggestions are eliding over this and useing and using an actual number .. notice the lack of single-quotes in their code.

You say you always want a comma after the first three "numbers" (characters), which makes no sense from a numerical/mathematical sense.  So just use INSTR and insert the comma:

```
select substr('123456789',1,3)||','||substr('123456789',4) from dual:
```

If the source data is actually a *number*, then pass it to to_char, and wrap that in substr:

```
select substr(to_char(123456789),1,3)||','||substr(to_char(123456789,4) from dual:
```